# Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManagerBean'

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I get Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManagerBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

What i do bad ?

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers( "/login","/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("Admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a parent `AuthenticationManager` it should be:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers( "/login","/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("Admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

And if you do, then you'll either have to rename the *parent*, or name this *child* `Bean` something else:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Option 1) rename the parent somewhere else, like so....
    private final AuthenticationManager parentAuthenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfig(AuthenticationManager parentAuthenticationManager) {
        this.parentAuthenticationManager = parentAuthenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    // Option 2) rename the child AuthenticationManager here
    @Bean("childAuthenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers( "/login","/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("Admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a `parentAuthenticationManager` then the second option will also yield that error for you. Where are you defining the parent?

Comment: In this class I defining parentAuthenticationManager

Comment: Ah, so you'll have to use the first option if you don't have a parent. You can't set the same bean to be it's parent.

Comment: Ok but I want use auth.parentAuthenticationManager

Comment: What's the name of your parent Auth bean?

Comment: authenticationManager

Comment: Then you have to re-name it so that the child name doesn't conflict with that name

Comment: But I can't re-name it in class WebSecurityConfigureAdapter , so what should I do ?

Comment: So you set up another WSCA? You can rename it there with `@Bean("parentAuthenticationManager")` over the object